# About Mvc routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to set a rule only for `defaultController`

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "testDefault",
     url: "Default/{action}/{id}.html",
     defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { 
          controller = "Test", 
          action = "Show", 
          id = UrlParameter.Optional 
     }
);
```

However, http://10.12.2.37:120/test/show/2.html also can be opened. This is not what I want. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why can't you just delete default route mapping? :)

Comment: Beacause  i want  other controller  use the default route mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing constraints:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "testDefault",
     url: "Default/{action}/{id}.html",
     defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
     constraints: new {
          id = @"\d+"
     }
 );
 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { 
          controller = "Test", 
          action = "Show", 
          id = UrlParameter.Optional 
     },
     constraints: new {
          id = @"\d+"
     }
);
```

I would also reccomend that you use route testing tool such as [routedebugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/) from Phil Haack. You can get it using [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/).

Comment: Thanks  .I think i konow it